# Delete and Insert data data if data if day exists and insert data if day does not exist

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have the below script that works however I need some help modifying it.

What I now need to do are the following
1. If the day already exists I need to delete all data from that day and insert the new data for the day.
2. if the day does not exist I need to insert the data for the day.

My date format is written as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss 
In it's current form it only inserts data if the current day is greater than the previous day.

```
Declare @Date As Date
SET @Date = (SELECT Max(CONVERT(char(10),[Date],102)) FROM [dbo].[ESOEmail_Monthly$])
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ESOEmail_Monthly$]
SELECT      [EMP_ID]
       ,[NAME]
       ,[DEPT]
       ,[DATE]
       ,[End Time]
       ,[LOGOUT]
       ,[ESO]
       ,[Team Manager]
       ,[Senior Manager]
       ,[SITE]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                     'Excel 12.0;Database=\\VF_RSOSDCNASUDA\fidopost\National_Command\National Command Centre\SQL\ESO\ESO.xlsm;HDR=YES',
                     'SELECT * FROM [ESOEmail$]')
WHERE (CONVERT(char(10),[Date],102) > CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date, 102))
```

Comment: Have a look at `MERGE` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks for the info Alex.  I took a quick look and not sure how I would implement this from a file that I'm trying to insert. Would I need to dump the new data first to a temp table and then do the updates or is there a way I can directly do this from the excel file that I'm trying to update?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to say in your previous comment. The way I read your question is that you have an Excel file that needs to be imported into a database table. You have some existing method that does it already and you want to change/enhance it. I suggested that you can try to use `MERGE` as it will allow you to implement your logic in one statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but it did not work out for me. When I tried to merge a date that did not exists in the target table all my other dates were delete and replaced with just the single date I was trying to insert.  Luckily I always make backup before testing like this. My understanding of merge is that it will try to sync my target table to source table.  Maybe I'm not getting the concept correct but that is how I understand it.

Comment: it works the other way, it syncs **source** to **target** . Target is the table that would get get changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around and finding some help I was able to find a solution that worked for me. I've posted the solution.

```
Declare @Date As DATE

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#1','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #1

SELECT      [EMP_ID]
   ,[NAME]
   ,[DEPT]
   ,[DATE]
   ,[End Time]
   ,[LOGOUT]
   ,[ESO]
   ,[Team Manager]
   ,[Senior Manager]
   ,[SITE]
INTO #1
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                 'Excel 12.0;Database=\\VF_RSOSDCNASUDA\fidopost\National_Command\National Command Centre\SQL\ESO\ESO.xlsm;HDR=YES',
                 'SELECT * FROM [ESOEmail$]');

SELECT TOP 1 @Date=[DATE] FROM #1

--DELETE
DELETE [dbo].[ESOEmail_Monthly$] WHERE CONVERT(char(10),[Date],102)=@Date;

--INSERT
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ESOEmail_Monthly$]
SELECT      [EMP_ID]
   ,[NAME]
   ,[DEPT]
   ,[DATE]
   ,[End Time]
   ,[LOGOUT]
   ,[ESO]
   ,[Team Manager]
   ,[Senior Manager]
   ,[SITE]
FROM #1
DROP TABLE #1
```